# Performance analysis of openmp code (parallel) vs serial code

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, performance-testing

How do I compare the performance of parallel code(using OpenMP) vs serial code? I am using the following method

```
int arr[1000] = {1, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 7, 3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 0, 9, 6, 5, 9, 5, 9, 2, 5, 8, 6, 1, 0, 7, 7, 3, 2, 8, 3, 2, 3, 7, 2, 0, 7, 2, 9, 5, 8, 6, 2, 8, 5, 8, 5, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 6, 2, 1, 9, 0, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 6, 3, 0, 8, 0, 8, 4, 2, 7, 1, 0, 2, 7, 6, 9, 7, 7, 5, 4, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 0, 8, 9, 2, 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 4, 8, 8, 1, 4, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8, 9, 9, 1, 4, 1, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 0, 0, 4, 2, 4, 9, 7, 6, 0, 3, 4, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 0, 8, 7, 7, 8, 0, 3, 8, 8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 6, 1, 4, 0, 4, 8, 5, 9, 4, 4, 7, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 1, 7, 8, 4, 3, 0, 8, 1, 5, 8, 7, 1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8, 6, 4, 6, 1, 7, 8, 1, 0, 3, 9, 7, 6, 7, 2, 1, 1, 8, 2, 9, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 1, 7, 7, 9, 6, 9, 2, 7, 9, 4, 8, 2, 7, 5, 0, 7, 3, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 2, 9, 1, 1, 5, 8, 4, 4, 5, 4, 0, 6, 6, 9, 8, 1, 7, 0, 0, 4, 2, 7, 9, 6, 2, 9, 7, 9, 1, 0, 4, 3, 0, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 6, 4, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 9, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 9, 1, 1, 0, 4, 9, 5, 7, 3, 9, 1, 5, 5, 5, 9, 2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 0, 9, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7, 5, 7, 1, 0, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 3, 5, 9, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 0, 9, 7, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 7, 3, 9, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 9, 7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 9, 7, 8, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 2, 4, 0, 4, 6, 9, 9, 5, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6, 9, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 1, 0, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 0, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8, 8, 2, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 6, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 0, 7, 1, 7, 0, 3, 8, 6, 6, 2, 6, 2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0, 4, 6, 3, 2, 0, 8, 5, 8, 2, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 9, 3, 3, 8, 7, 9, 0, 7, 1, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 5, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 9, 2, 6, 0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7, 9, 5, 7, 1, 4, 0, 7, 7, 9, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 0, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 6, 8, 4, 3, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 8, 3, 6, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 4, 7, 7, 0, 9, 6, 1, 1, 8, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 6, 5, 1, 7, 7, 4, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 0, 9, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 0, 8, 1, 8, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 9, 1, 0, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 9, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9, 0, 1, 4, 8, 4, 9, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 4, 0, 9, 7, 2, 3, 5, 1, 9, 7, 3, 5, 9, 0, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 5, 1, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4, 7, 7, 0, 9, 6, 8, 2, 9, 3, 5, 9, 2, 8, 4, 2, 0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3, 0, 6, 7, 1, 5, 1, 0, 2, 2, 9, 0, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 0, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 9, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 9, 3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 9, 3, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 9, 5, 9, 2, 0, 3, 8, 5, 2, 4, 2, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 9, 3, 2, 7, 6, 0, 7, 2, 6, 8, 0, 5, 5, 9, 9, 5, 4, 8, 0, 7, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 0, 5, 9, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9, 0, 2, 7, 2, 9, 0, 9, 9, 2, 6, 4, 3, 6, 9, 7, 6, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, 9, 9, 6, 6, 0, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 8, 8, 1, 0, 9, 3, 9, 8, 5, 6, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 0, 7, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3, 2, 5, 9, 2, 7, 1, 0, 5, 6, 0, 4};

clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();
/* here, do your time-consuming job */

    #pragma omp parallel for private(temp)
    for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
        temp = arr[j];
        for(i=0;i<temp;temp--)
        result[j]=result[j]*temp;
    }   


end = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("\n\n%f",time_spent);
```

But every time I run the code I get a different output. I want to see how the performance of the code differs for openmp and serial code. What method I should use to achieve the same?

Comment: Unless you're using MSVC or MinGW (but not MinGW-w64) don't use `clock()`. I suggest you use `omp_get_wtime()` since it does what you want for all compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time the code takes to run will change a little bit due to computer/server usage; however, if you run both the parallel and serial versions you should see a difference in the amount of run time between the two.  Also, the size of your parallel operation is pretty small.  But you should see and improvement.

```
int arr[1000] = {1, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 7, 3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 0, 9, 6, 5, 9, 5, 9, 2, 5, 8, 6, 1, 0, 7, 7, 3, 2, 8, 3, 2, 3, 7, 2, 0, 7, 2, 9, 5, 8, 6, 2, 8, 5, 8, 5, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 6, 2, 1, 9, 0, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 6, 3, 0, 8, 0, 8, 4, 2, 7, 1, 0, 2, 7, 6, 9, 7, 7, 5, 4, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 0, 8, 9, 2, 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 4, 8, 8, 1, 4, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8, 9, 9, 1, 4, 1, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 0, 0, 4, 2, 4, 9, 7, 6, 0, 3, 4, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 0, 8, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 0, 8, 7, 7, 8, 0, 3, 8, 8, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 9, 8, 6, 1, 4, 0, 4, 8, 5, 9, 4, 4, 7, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9, 1, 7, 8, 4, 3, 0, 8, 1, 5, 8, 7, 1, 7, 2, 5, 2, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 9, 1, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8, 6, 4, 6, 1, 7, 8, 1, 0, 3, 9, 7, 6, 7, 2, 1, 1, 8, 2, 9, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 1, 7, 7, 9, 6, 9, 2, 7, 9, 4, 8, 2, 7, 5, 0, 7, 3, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 2, 9, 1, 1, 5, 8, 4, 4, 5, 4, 0, 6, 6, 9, 8, 1, 7, 0, 0, 4, 2, 7, 9, 6, 2, 9, 7, 9, 1, 0, 4, 3, 0, 7, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 6, 4, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 9, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 9, 1, 1, 0, 4, 9, 5, 7, 3, 9, 1, 5, 5, 5, 9, 2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 0, 9, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7, 5, 7, 1, 0, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 3, 5, 9, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 0, 9, 7, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 7, 3, 9, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 9, 7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 9, 7, 8, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 2, 4, 0, 4, 6, 9, 9, 5, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6, 9, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 6, 6, 1, 0, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 0, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8, 8, 2, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 6, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 0, 7, 1, 7, 0, 3, 8, 6, 6, 2, 6, 2, 7, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0, 4, 6, 3, 2, 0, 8, 5, 8, 2, 7, 2, 6, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 9, 3, 3, 8, 7, 9, 0, 7, 1, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 5, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 9, 2, 6, 0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 7, 9, 5, 7, 1, 4, 0, 7, 7, 9, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 0, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 6, 8, 4, 3, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 8, 3, 6, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 4, 7, 7, 0, 9, 6, 1, 1, 8, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 6, 5, 1, 7, 7, 4, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 0, 9, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 0, 8, 1, 8, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 9, 1, 0, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 9, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9, 0, 1, 4, 8, 4, 9, 2, 7, 9, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 4, 0, 9, 7, 2, 3, 5, 1, 9, 7, 3, 5, 9, 0, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 5, 1, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4, 7, 7, 0, 9, 6, 8, 2, 9, 3, 5, 9, 2, 8, 4, 2, 0, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3, 0, 6, 7, 1, 5, 1, 0, 2, 2, 9, 0, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 0, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 9, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 9, 3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 9, 3, 2, 6, 8, 2, 6, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 9, 5, 9, 2, 0, 3, 8, 5, 2, 4, 2, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 9, 3, 2, 7, 6, 0, 7, 2, 6, 8, 0, 5, 5, 9, 9, 5, 4, 8, 0, 7, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 0, 5, 9, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9, 0, 2, 7, 2, 9, 0, 9, 9, 2, 6, 4, 3, 6, 9, 7, 6, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, 9, 9, 6, 6, 0, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 8, 8, 1, 0, 9, 3, 9, 8, 5, 6, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 0, 7, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3, 2, 5, 9, 2, 7, 1, 0, 5, 6, 0, 4};

clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent_omp;
double time_spent;

begin = omp_get_wtime();
/* here, do your time-consuming job */

#pragma omp parallel for private(temp)
for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
    temp = arr[j];
    for(i=0;i<temp;temp--)
    result[j]=result[j]*temp;
}   


end = omp_get_wtime();
time_spent_omp = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

begin = omp_get_wtime();
/* here, do your time-consuming job */

for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
    temp = arr[j];
    for(i=0;i<temp;temp--)
    result[j]=result[j]*temp;
}   


end = omp_get_wtime();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("\n\n Time to process: %f --- Time to process with OPENMP %f",time_spent, time_spent_omp);
```

This should give you a better idea about how it is working.

Comment: Please don't suggest `clock()`! Use `omp_get_wtime()`.